# Tofu character on Workbench

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-font-family

Everything else is OK, but can not display right text on Popup and Menu.

[image: character]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of problems usually happen when you have invalid permissions on font files. The solution lies in detecting the font file and correcting its permission.

Since, Most of the font files reside in `/usr/share/fonts`, you can apply a generic fix on them.

First make `root` the owner of all files and dirs in `/usr/share/fonts/`

```
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/share/fonts -v
```

Then change all folders visitable by fixing permissions on them

```
find /usr/share/fonts -type d -exec sudo chmod -v 755 {} +
```

Then use this command to fix permissions on font files.

```
find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*.[ot]tf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644 {} +
```

This command lists all files with `.ttf` and `.otf` extension and change the permissions of them to `644`, required permission bits for fonts.

You can use this command to change all files permissions to `644`.

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/share/fonts
```

Comment: It might also be useful to assure that all find files are owned by root: `sudo chown -R root:root /usr/share/fonts`

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: I also noticed that the first `find` may fail to discover some files if they're inside unreadable or untraversable directories, yet those are only fixed in the second `find` command.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I had same suspicion, but In my test, with `sudo` order doesn't matter

Comment: `find` doesn't run with super-user privileges the way you wrote it so it couldn't find files inside directories without read and traversal permissions for the executing user. While `chmod` runs with super-user privileges it only acts on the files provided by `find`.