# unreadable text even after installing urdu font

Tags: 16.04, fonts, gedit

I have downloaded and installed [google noto fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) on ubuntu 16.04.
I have no idea why gedit font preference dialog displays blocks of squares as shown in the picture below. I have already copied fonts to `/usr/share/fonts` and ran `sudo fc-cache -fv`.

**Note:** I have already tried the changing file permission as suggested in [tofu character on workbench](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836850/tofu-character-on-workbench) but it doesn't fix the problem.

**Update:** output of `fc-list | grep i noto`
`grep: noto: No such file or directory`
[image: gedit font preference dialog]

Comment: No immediate idea, but those fonts are available via the `fonts-noto` package in the Ubuntu archive. You may want to try installing that instead.

Comment: Tried that too, without any change. The problem persist.

Comment: Can you launch a guest session to see if the problem is present there?

Comment: yes the problem is there as well.

Comment: Then it's not something in $HOME which messes it up. Sorry, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: This is because of permission issues on the font. See the answer above the linked question

Comment: @Anwar No issues with file permission, I have confirmed it by issuing the commands suggested in the post you recommended but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @ImranAli Which command you used ?

Comment: in `/usr/share/fonts/` `find -iname '*.ttf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644 {} \; find -iname '*.otf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644 {} \;` and `find -iname '*.otf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644 {} \;` followed by `find -type d -exec sudo chmod -v 755 {} \;`

Comment: @ImranAli Can you give me the output of `fc-list | grep -i noto` ? Edit the question with that output